# What type of hinge is this?

Tags: refinishing, hinges, restoration

I have a hinge and I'm having a bear of a time replacing it.  It's from an old Bakers box and it's the cabinet/tray hinge and has a peculiar shape.  It hangs down a bit so the door is actually lower than the hinge and it can create a seal.  Here is a link to what the bakers box looks like:  [pic of bakers box](https://cdn.globalauctionplatform.com/c5667e02-10b4-4c68-8999-a60901109f73/f640e5ac-2736-4b83-805e-6abfef436c0a/540x360.jpg) 
Here is a pic of the hinge.  It's about 1.5" across and .75" wide
[image: Here is the hinge]
Here is the side of the hinge
[image: side of hinge]

What is this hinge?  Any ideas where I can find a replacement?

Comment: Is it just the hinge shown that is damaged? It may be possible to fix it, which would make things a lot simpler for you. A new pin, or the existing pin straightened, is often all that's really needed but it's not always possible to knock the original pin out on smaller hinges made from thinner metal.

Comment: This is the one in good condition.  The other one is completely warped and rusted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a "partial-wrap inset hinge". Places like Lee Valley have them.

Comment: @tjcinnamon, other names to look for are "inset partial wrap-around hinge", with and without the hyphen, and  "inset partial wraparound hinge". There are many slightly different versions of this type of hinge and it'll likely prove difficult to find an exact match, which means it might be necessary to replace them in pairs (they're often sold in pairs anyway).

Comment: Indeed. The best part about most natural language web search tech these days is that hyphens and word-stem placement is often not very significant. Not true for places like the (for example) Lee Valley web search, unfortunately. That being said, I'm often surprised at how much obscure woodworking stuff there is hiding on Amazon.

Comment: I ordered some partial-wrap inset and they look similar.  I just got a response from DoorWare.com and they called it a no-mortise lid hinge.  https://www.rockler.com/separable-hinges-for-lids?sid=V9146